# how to add cancel button inside spinner

Tags: java, android

I want to add cancel button inside of spinner how to add cancel button in spinner without

using alert dialog please give me an example..

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.test_list_item,stringArray);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner.setAdapter((adapter));
```

Comment: Why do you you need cancel button in Spinner??

Comment: some times i dnt need spinner in that time when am clicking cancel button close the spinner that why i need cancel button.

Comment: There is no need to add a cancel button as the back button of the device will cancel the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of an ugly UI implementation if you ask me but maybe I'm wrong (haven't seen your project so I cant judge)

Anyway I haven't tried this but I believe it is a simple matter of creating your own spinner_row xml file (start with the androids simple_spinner_item) and add a button with an `invisiblity=invisible` property and extend your own `ArrayAdapter` and on the wanted row (eg: if `pos==array.length()`) change the buttons property to visible.

Another option is to simply inflate another row wherever you want the button to be (again its the same procedure- create your own row xml file with the button (visible this time) and then inside your `ArrayAdapter` inflate this xml).

There are plenty of tutorials and Q&As about each and every step in this breakdown

Hope it helps!